# How to fix parsing error for datetimestamp in a pandas column

Tags: python, datetime, parsing

I have a .eml file and I extract contents into pandas for further data analysis. One of the columns is a datetime field in the format `Thu 07 Mar 2019 01:24:41 -0500`

I tried to use `datetime` library to strip the date/time and store it in separate columns. Code below

```
       df_res.DateTime . // name of the dataframe 

       OUTPUT: 
       0       Thu, 07 Mar 2019 01:24:41 -0500
       1       Wed, 06 Mar 2019 14:40:26 -0800
       2       Tue, 05 Mar 2019 07:00:53 +0000
       3       Wed, 06 Mar 2019 19:40:06 +0000
       4       Mon, 04 Mar 2019 12:57:01 +0000
       5       Tue, 05 Mar 2019 02:40:28 +0000        


      date = datetime.datetime.strptime(df_res['DateTime'], "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"])



      ERROR: KeyError: ('Thu 07 Mar 2019 01:24:41 -0500\t', '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't give me the date and time in a new column. The format seems correct.

Comment: Have you tried making the Series [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) like this: `df_res['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_res['DateTime'], format= "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")`?

Comment: Yes @Alex, I tried that I get an error : `TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>`

Comment: can you provide the first few lines of the file? Or a copy of the head of the DataFrame?